# Correct way of dynamic memory allocation for high-dimensional arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was wondering what is the easiest and of course most accurate way for dynamic memory allocation for a 4-D array in C++. What I already know is the following:

```
double**** A;
A = new double***[s1];
for (i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
    A[i] = new double**[s2];
    for (j = 0; j < s2; j++) {
        A[i][j] = new double*[s3]; 
        for (k = 0; k < s3; k++) {
            A[i][j][k] = new double[s4];
        }
    }
}
```

to declare `A` as a 4-D array of dimensions `s1`x`s2`x`s3`x`s4`.

However, the above is not safe. In the sense that if one of the `new`s fail to allocate the memory the loops continue without noticing this.

To make the above a bit safer, we can enclose it in a `try`/`catch` block so that the code does not continue after a `bad_alloc` has been thrown by `new` and the code will not try to access some non-existent memory elements and the program can halt at this point.

This is OK with the exception that the memory that has already been allocated will not be released before the program finishes. Theoretically with the values of `i`, `j`, and `k` we must be able to precisely say which memory elements are already allocated and release them. But I cannot think of a straightforward way of doing it.

For a 2-D case I would do something like this:

```
double** A;
try {    
    A = new double*[s1];
} catch(bad_alloc& ba) {
    delete[] A;
    throw ba; // or end the program
}
try {
    for (i = 0; i < s1; i++)
        A[i] = new double[s2];
} catch(bad_alloc& ba) {
    while(--i) {
        delete[] A[i];
    }
    delete[] A;
    throw ba; // or end the prog.
}
```

The above could be generalized to higher dimensional arrays but I guess it would be very ugly! So I wonder if there is a better way for doing that?

---

I guess I should also mention that in my case `A[i][j][k]` is a vector with very few non-zero elements. Hence, I only take `s3` to be as big as the number of non-zero elements (and then take care of mapping indices and ... later). `s3`, however, depends on `j`. That's why using the traditional memory allocation is easier than higher-level APIs like `vector`

Comment: [Boost Multi Array.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) @StoryTeller - With all due respect to `std::vector`, nesting 4 is horrible.

Comment: @jrok, nesting more than 2 of anything is horrible. It's nice to learn about multi-array, though, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for both comments. Indeed, in addition to the fact that nesting 4 `std::vectors` is horrible, I am using the old-style arrays simply because in my case `A[i][j][k]` is a vector with very few non-zero elements. Hence, I only take `s3` to be as big as the number of non-zero elements (and then take care of mapping indices and ... later). `s3`, however, depends on `j`. That's why using the traditional memory allocation is easier.

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi "traditional memory allocation is easier" - completely false statement.  If you need a `vector` of a set size, use the reserve methods.  If you need a static array, use the `array` template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>> A;
```

That will get you a 4D dynamic array without the worry of managing the exception safety (for memory allocations at least).

If you want a static array:

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<std::array<double, N>, N>, N>, N> B;
```

Side Note:  If you are nesting that far, you can probably gain a lot through refactoring.

> That's why using the traditional memory allocation is easier than
>   higher-level APIs like vector

That is a flawed assertion.  You have a non-sparse 4D array - you gain next to nothing by using "traditional memory allocation" over using `std::vector` or `std::array` or even a Boost Multiarray.  All of the same steps you have to take for proper memory management and exception safety are already done (and well tested) in those classes, whereas a custom implementation is not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Just a very silly question, as I'm not very familiar with `vector`: Do I need to call `A.clear()` in the destructor of the class containing the array to liberate the allocated memory or it is redundant?

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi No.  By default, the destructor for the vectors will be called clearing out the memory.  As a side note, `clear()` doesn't actually release the memory of a vector.

Answer (score 2):

If you really must have a block of memory which is an N-d array, you could try the following:

```
int* raw_mem = new int [S1 * S2 * S3];
int (*arr)[S2][S3] = (int (*)[S2][S3]) raw_mem;
```

This merely has the block of memory be addressed like a true 3-d array.

Now, this is the worst way to do it. You should use some higher level API that is suggested in other answers. But it is possible to treat a block of memory as a C multi-array.

Comment: +1 Nice casting. I wonder, is it a well-formed code over different compilers?

Comment: @M.M. I'm without my copy of the standards, but I'm pretty sure it is well defined for every standard compliant compiler.

Comment: You may use a 'placement new' instead of casting.

Comment: @Jarod42, I'm not sure I follow. What does placement new has to do with indexing modes?

Comment: I'm thinking about `int (*arr)[S2][S3] = new (raw_mem) int[S1][S2][S3];`. But then, I realise that it doesn't work when `S2` or `S3` is not const.